# How to prove that $\forall$ Riemannian manifold $M$, $T\in C^{1}(M)$ and $x,y\in M$ close enough: $d(Ty,exp_{Tx}(D_xTexp^{-1}_xy))\leq d(x,y)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> How to prove that $\forall$ Riemannian manifold $M$, $T\in C^{1}(M)$ and $x,y\in M$ close enough: $$d(Ty,\exp_{Tx}(D_xT\ \exp^{-1}_xy))\leq d(x,y)$$

My attempts so far were only able to show the inequality up to a multiplicative constant depending on $T$, which is not good enough. This should be true as it appears in the book 
"Smooth ergodic theory for endomorphisms", and is true for the euclidean case.

*I was able to show the requested result under the assumption that there exists a small enough *neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that, it can be mapped isometrically to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, or some neighborhood in it *($dimM=n$) with normal euclidean metric- is that statement true?

-I now know that the suggested statement with *'s infront of the lines is incorrect.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the quantifiers you want on $x, y$? For instance, the following appears to be false, even in the Euclidean case: "Given $T$, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for $d(x,y) < \epsilon$ [your inequality holds]". (Counterexample: consider a diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^2$ having fixed points at each $(N,0)$ and looking locally like a translate of $(r, \theta) \mapsto (r, \theta + Nr)$ near such a point.)

Comment: Hi mollyerin, thanks for trying to help. In fact since I've proven this claim in some small enough neighborhood, using A LOT of epsilo-delta arguments. Thanks